# Error sending whatsapp message using template

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to send the following template:

```
Estimado {{1}}

Adjunto le envío nuestra propuesta comercial, para que lo analice y tome la mejor decisión para su empresa.

Me encuentro atento para aclarar cualquier duda o comentario que pueda surgir.

Saludos!

Atte,
*sameName*
Cel. *SomeTel*
Correo electrónico: *SomeEmail*
```

But when I create the string in php with the following text, Twilio still takes the message like a free message instead of taking it like a template.

```php
<pre><code>
`$messageBody = Estimado [name]'.PHP_EOL.'Adjunto le envío nuestra propuesta comercial, para que lo analice y tome la mejor decisión para su empresa.'.PHP_EOL.'Me encuentro atento para aclarar cualquier duda o comentario que pueda surgir.'.PHP_EOL.'Saludos!'.PHP_EOL.'Atte,'.PHP_EOL.'[name]'.PHP_EOL.'Cel. [tel]'.PHP_EOL.'Correo electrónico: [some email]';`
</code></pre>
```

If I start a 24 session I don't have any problem to send any message.

An example of how to use whatsapp templates in php and twilio.

Comment: I [edit]ed; mostly to avoid the wrong impression that the question is non-English, because that impression would get it closed quickly. I also tried to help a bit with the language. But I am not entirely sure I fully got that part. So please review and fix wherever I broke your meaning. The last sentence confuses me, it seems that it refers to something you have not yet added. In case I broke something, please accept my apology; though I am sure that even that way I acted in your best interest.

Comment: [From docs] _"Twilio will send the message as a templated message if it matches one of the approved templates. If the body does not match a pre-registered template, the message will be sent as a freeform message."_ - it doesn't say exactly how they check for a "match", but seeing that your template has empty lines, but in your code you are inserting only a _single_ `PHP_EOL` in those places - that might already be enough of a "mismatch" for it not to be recognized as a filled-out version of the template ...?

Answer (score 0):

Templated message must exactly match with the approved template, including spaces and line breaks.

For example, if you approved template is like this:

```
Hello {{1}},
How are you?
```

It won't work if you try to send a message like this:

```
Hello John, How are you?
```

The message you are sending has to be:

```
Hello John,
How are you?
```